# lmfit is installed but importing lmfit in python fails. Suggestions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, package

I am trying to set up some software on Ubuntu 14.04 VM. It is python code that requires the lmfit package. I have run "pip install lmfit", which is successful, and running it again simply states that it is already installed:

```
kyle@kyle-VirtualBox:~/projects/MOSAIC$ pip install lmfit==0.7.4
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lmfit==0.7.4 in /home/kyle/.virtualenvs/MOSAIC/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

However, when I am using python, if I try to import lmfit, I get this error:

```
>>> import lmfit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lmfit
```

Any suggestions for how to proceed? Why is the package not available within python?

Comment: It looks like you're installing the module in a virtualenv from the log. Have you sourced that env before importing the module ?

Comment: try calling `python` in your command terminal and then try `>>> import lmfit` and see if that works?

Comment: @bvidal It's possible that I haven't. I am following install instructions on their website exactly, but I don't recall that being one of the steps. How would I do that?

Comment: @Anmol_uppal - that's exactly what I did - the output from that command is included in the OP.

Comment: @KBriggs then check your code editor? are you using canopy ? it sometimes gives rise to conflicts .

Comment: The `pip` install command outputs it is already installed in `/home/kyle/.virtualenvs/MOSAIC` so you should run `source  /home/kyle/.virtualenvs/MOSAIC/bin/activate` and re-test from your python interpreter

Comment: @bvidal that worked in the interpreter, but when running the code itself I still get the same error.

Comment: That's because you need to source the env before running the code. I suggest reading about virtualenv and how to manage them.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I did git clone "http://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py.git" and installed using "python setup.py install" in the folder where I pulled the code form github. Then I added this folder to the PATH in "Environment Variables". It works well.